# Change the exposed graphql schema through directives

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

Directives are nice to alter the behaviour of resolvers, but is there a way to directly change the exposed schema with them?

Example

*expected superuser schema*

```
type Query {
  getBooks: [Book]
  getAuthors: [Author]
}
```

*expected normal user schema*

```
type Query {
  getBooks: [Book]
}
```

*one definition to build them all*

```
type Query {
  getBooks: [Book] @allow(scopes: ["superuser"])
  getAuthors: [Author]
}
```

The scope would be defined through the given context as i would build one schema for each possible scope.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. "as I would build one schema for each possible scope"... so are you maintaining two separate schemas and/or endpoints? Or do you simply want to change the behavior of a field depending on whether the user is a superuser or a regular user?

Comment: yes, i want to expose two different endpoints. Behaviour would be doable with resolvers, but i want the fields to be gone from the schema completly

Comment: Then I'm still unclear on what behavior you're trying to implement. Are you trying to maintain a single schema for both endpoints? Can you please provide some additional details around expected behavior and why what you've already tried isn't working?